# Social open graph attributes not working in my Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

I try to add page specific open graph and twitter meta tags to my Nuxt.js application. Therefore, I have some page specific attributes

```js
export default {
    // ...
    head () {
        return {
            meta: [
                { name: 'og:title', content: this.tool.title },
                { name: 'og:description', content: this.tool.description },
                // Twitter meta settings
                { name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary' },
                { name: 'twitter:site', content: '@me' },
                { property: 'twitter:domain', content: 'me.me' },
                { property: 'twitter:url', content: `https://me.me/${this.tool.slug}` },
                { name: 'twitter:title', content: this.tool.title },
                { name: 'twitter:description', content: this.tool.description },
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

Plus some starter meta tags in my `nuxt.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    head: {
        // ...
        meta: [
            // ...
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content: 'Thats me!'
            },
            { hid: 'og:url', property: 'og:url', content: 'https://me.me' },
            { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: 'me.me' },
            { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: '/favicon-96x96.png' },
            { hid: 'og:type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
            {
                hid: 'og:description',
                property: 'og:description',
                content: 'This is the one and only me'
            },
            { hid: 'twitter:card', name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary' },
            { hid: 'twitter:site', name: 'twitter:site', content: '@me' },
```

However, when I add the page link to a tweet, it only shows the information from my `nuxt.config.js`. Also, using the Twitter card validator or [another open graph checker](https://www.opengraph.xyz/url/https:%2F%2Fdialogik.tv%2Ftool%2Fnightbot-dd79c10d-3627-41d8-8a7a-5ad161019be4/) doesn't show the page specific meta attributes.

I am setting page specific meta information in a single file component (in `/components`) and not directly in a page file (`/pages` directory). Just in case this is a source of failure.

When I inspect my page source code, I can see that the meta tags are present as expected.

[image: Sourcecode screenshot]

Do you have any idea what might be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt.js uses [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) to update the document head and meta attributes of your application. It uses the hid key to identify the meta tags, which you are missing in your component. The following should work for you:

```js
export default {
    // ...
    head () {
        return {
            meta: [
                { name: 'og:title', hid='og:title', content: this.tool.title },
                { name: 'og:description', hid='og:description', content: this.tool.description },
                // Twitter meta settings
                { name: 'twitter:card', hid='twitter:card', content: 'summary' },
                { name: 'twitter:site', hid='twitter:side', content: '@me' },
                { property: 'twitter:domain', hid='twitter:domain', content: 'me.me' },
                { property: 'twitter:url', hid='twitter:url', content: `https://me.me/${this.tool.slug}` },
                { name: 'twitter:title', hid='twitter:title', content: this.tool.title },
                { name: 'twitter:description', hid='twitter:desccription', content: this.tool.description },
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't change anything at all.

Comment: Hey @GottliebNotschnabel, could you upload your code to a playground? I'd like to take a look and fix the issue for you!

Comment: Hey @smartius thank you for taking a look. The code is [on github](https://github.com/dialogik-tv/dialogiktv-frontend/blob/master/components/Tool.vue#L248) and you can see the live code on [dialogik.tv](https://dialogik.tv/tool/twitch-follower-remover-1bb81d9f-913a-4377-8053-e550924a190d)

Comment: Hello @Gottlieb Notschnabel. I am facing the same issue. Did you get it working? I can see the generation of the meta content but when I use the open graph validator (https://www.opengraph.xyz/) it gives missing image. When I put the URL on the browser, it shows up. Thanks

Comment: In my case I am using Nuxt as a static generator. And I think it dynamically updates the `<head>` via Javascript. And since I am using it as a preview, this javascript does not get executed. I think this would be the reason for the og:image showing blank during the thumbnail or link preview process